# copy files created in one folder to multiple other folders on linux

Tags: linux, centos, files, copy

I'm looking for a way to copy photos that are uploaded to one folder to many other folders and visa versa.

Example: a photo is uploaded to folder 1, it is then copied to folders 2-5. And if a photo is uploaded to folder 2 it is copied to folders 1 and 3-5.

I'm running CentOS 5. All of these folders are on the same server.

I came across another post on here that talked about incron, but that type of programming is over my head.

Comment: incron is not programming. It's just installing a daemon, creating a slightly-opaque-but-not-awful-at-least-it's-documented incrontab config file, and *maybe* a simple shell script to do the work.

Answer (score 1):

rsync will do the job.

you need to setup a cron job from a shell script that what it does is running rsync over all your directories.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of rsync, check out [unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/) - it handles synchronizing two directories better than rsync.

I can envision doing this with a bash script running a series of unison commands to keep all the directories in sync:

```
for i in 2 3 4
do
  unison /dir1 /dir$i
done
```

put that in a crontab that runs every hour or whatever ( I realize my unison syntax is not right).

However, I do really like the [incrond approach](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-inotify-examples-to-replicate-directories/). That would give you a cleaner design because it would allow you to only run the synchronizer when one of the directories change.  However indeed it's more work to set up.